# Update a model with nested collection, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I'd appreciate any advice.

I've been searching for the right approach of modifying a collection, but not sure which is the best one.

I've an entity with nested collection:

```
public class Customer
{
    //customer properties
    ICollection <Address> Addresses{get; set;}
}
```

My `Edit` view for `Customer` includes the `Addresses` as well, i.e. user adds Addresses dynamically, and the whole collection is passed to the controller on form submittion.
In the controller I update the `Customer` as usually:

```
Context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

And also I have to update the collection of `Address`:

```
customer.Addresses.ToList()
                  .ForEach(p => 
                          Context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified);
```

It works fine untill I add a new record to `Addresses`. Since it doesn't exist in DB, saving throws the error.

I know I could check if the entry exists in DB - modify, otherwise - add.

But there's a problem in `Address` entity. It's primary key, say `ID`, is Identity, i.e. auto-increments when inserted to DB.

So, initially in the collection new `Address` will have `ID` equal to `0`. Then if I add one `Address` to the context, then before adding another one,I check if the second `Address` is in context, it will return true, because the first one is also with `ID` = 0.

Also, okay, I can drop the whole collection and add it again, but it can affect the performance.

So, I'd be so grateful for your advices.

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate over the addresses and check the `id`. Based on the value it is possible to set the state of the entity entry to `Added` or `Modified`.  In that case you don't have to recreate the collection.

```
    foreach (var a in customer.Addresses)
    {
              model.Entry(a).State = a.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added :EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

You could use the same approach for the customer of course.

Comment: What if some of entries deleted? Check for the rest ones in DB to exist in current collection? I hoped there is more elegant solution.

Comment: Entity Framework will remove the deleted entries from your database.